# Move document to root path by workflow

Tags: workflow, document, move, path

I'm currently assigning permissions to documents by inheriting from folders. So everytime a document will be checked in a workflow starts which changes the property "path and name" to the appropriate folder and name of the document. That works well. The folders are invisible for users.

The problem: 
If I want to check in an existing document it will be uploaded to the root path. So it exists twice. My approach was to move the document the time it will be checked out to the root path, so the uploaded document overwrites the existing. After Check-In it will be moved to the right folder anyway. The problem is setting the property "Path and name" to the root path is not working.

For example:
The documents URL is "http:// testsite/testlibrary/testfolder/blubb.xls"
Moving it to folder "testfolder2" by setting "path and name" to "testfolder2/[Current Item:Name]" works well.
Moving it to the URL "http:// testsite/testlibrary/" by setting "path and name" doesn't work.

I tried

- "http:// testsite/testlibrary/[Current Item:Name]"
- "/testlibrary/[Current Item:Name]"
- "testlibrary/[Current Item:Name]"
- "/[Current Item:Name]"
- "[Current Item:Name]"

Any Idea how to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a Content Organizer library? Path is relative within the library folders, so moving it to `/testlibrary/` will make it look for a subfolder named that... not a parent folder.

You could also consider copy and delete. It would maintain metadata, but probably not version history – though I'd have to test it.